# Version solving errror with firebase in flutter with some dependancies

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm getting version-solving errors when trying to add firebase to my flutter project. I have already configured firebase on os and the last step is running flutter pub get. I commented out basic_utils to see if there would be any other conflicts, which is why I know it won't work with google_fonts either. Anybody know what I am doing wrong here? I suspect there are other dependencies that it will conflict with. Is this just something where I have to use an older version of firebase to make it work?

```
So, because jd_app depends on both firebase_storage ^8.0.0 and google_fonts ^1.1.1, version solving failed.

So, because jd_app depends on both basic_utils ^2.7.1 and firebase_auth ^1.0.1, version solving failed.
```

**Dependencies:**

> ```
> dependencies:
>   flutter:
>     sdk: flutter
>   basic_utils: ^2.7.1
>   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
>   firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
>   firebase_core: ^1.0.1
>   firebase_database: ^6.1.0
>   firebase_storage: ^8.0.0
>   flutter_svg: ^0.19.3
>   get: ^3.24.0
>   google_fonts: ^1.1.1
>   image: ^2.1.19
>   maps_launcher: ^1.2.2+2
>   provider: ^4.3.3
>   url_launcher: ^5.5.0
>   xml: ^4.2.0
>
> dev_dependencies:
>   flutter_test:
>     sdk: flutter
>   flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

These are currently the stable version of **firebase**

```
firebase_core: ^0.7.0
firebase_auth: ^0.20.1
firebase_storage: ^7.0.0
cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0+1
```

Comment: It did not work and it through another compatibility error, but this time with firebase_core. I dropped down firebase_core to a lower level and then I got a version conflict with firebase_database. Is it just going to be trial and error until I can get it to work or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

After a search on the web, it seems that version solving can be easily remedied by following the instructions from this website:

https://iiro.dev/2018/08/28/resolving-dart-package-version-conflicts/ .

According to the link, the dependencies in conflict should be allotted the value 'any.' For example:

```
firebase_database: any
```

Subsequently, enter *flutter packages get*, open the newly generated *pubspec.lock* file, and then change the version of the dependency in your *yaml* file to the one in the *lock* file. Run *flutter packages get* once more and there should be no more conflicts. At least I didn't have any.

Answer (score 0):

Update ALL the dependencies to the latest version. Check pub.dev to get the current versions